# Powershell List groups and members from AD and export to CSV

Tags: powershell

I created a CSV with all the group names. The following script reads all the groups names from the "group.csv" and list the group and members.

Script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
$csv = Get-Content "f:\Temp\group.csv"

$result = $csv | foreach-object {
$group=$_
get-qadgroupmember "$_" -sizelimit 0 -indirect | select-object samaccountname,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}
}
$result | export-csv f:\temp\groupandmem.csv -notypeinformation
```

There are more than 1000 groups in the "group.csv" with a lot of members in each. The executing of the script stops with a memory problem and nothing is written to the groupandmem.csv because this is done at last.

I have the following questions:

Is is possible to:
- For each group in the "group.csv", list the group from CSV, search the group in the AD, display the members and write the group name and the members to the users groupandmem.csv. Do this for all the groups in the "group.csv".

-The groupandmem.csv is filled as follows:

Row 1 group,member1,members2,members3.......

Row 2 group2,member1,members2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you start assigning things to variables then you are preventing powershell from "streaming" the users from one end of the pipe (AD) into the other end (the CSV file.) Instead, structure your pipeline like this:

```
Get-Content "f:\Temp\group.csv" | foreach-object {
    $group = $_ # grab current group name
    get-qadgroupmember $group -sizelimit 0 -indirect | `
        select-object samaccountname,@{n="GroupName";e={$group}}
} | export-csv f:\temp\groupandmem.csv -notypeinformation
```

Now there is a true "pipeline" from start to finish: `csv | foreach | get | transform | export`

Before, you were backing things up by assigning everything into a variable before passing it onto the next command.

*Updated: added $group to current capture group name (row)*

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the groupname and then all the members on the same row such as: Row 1 group,member1,members2,members3.......
Row 2 group2,member1,members2 etc.